# openMP and SSE, my program doesn't speed up

Tags: optimization, openmp, sse

Here is a part of my code which runs parallel:

```
timer.Start();
        for(int i = 0; i < params.epochs; ++i)
        {
            #pragma omp for
            for(int j = 0; j < min_net; ++j)
            {
                std::pair<CVectorSSE,CVectorSSE>& sample = data_set[j];
                nets[j]->Approximate(sample.first,net_outputs[j]);
                out_gradients[j].SetDifference(net_outputs[j],sample.second);
                nets[j]->BackPropagateGradient(out_gradients[j],net_gradients[j]);
            }

        }
        timer.Stop();
```

epochs = 100
I have AMD athlon X2 5000+
When I launch this code without omp directive the time is same...
And when I look on task manager / performance when runing both programs (with/without omp)
in both cases 2 cores are used... So it seems that VS (VS 2008) somehow optimizes code like omp???
The code inside parallel loop uses SSE instructions...
I was wondering that maybe in multicore procs there is only one SSE unit but it would be stupid...
So maybe some1 can tell me what i am doing wrong?
I know that it depends on my code inside the loop but if this code inside is parallel then it MUST speed up...

Okay I am definitly doing something wrong - look at this code:

```
time_t start;
time_t stop;

start = time(NULL);
#pragma omp for
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    Sleep(1000);
}
stop = time(NULL);

cout<<difftime(stop,start)<<endl;
```

without omp it should sleep for 10 secs (10*1000ms)
with omp it should sleep less than 10 secs because 2 threads can sleep in one time right?
BUT it sleeps again 10 secs - how it is possible?

Comment: You should **profile** the code and see where time is being spent - otherwise you're just guessing at where your performance problems lie

Answer (score 0):

I tried the second example on Linux with gcc. My program runs for 3 secs on Core i3. I guess the problem you are having is that you have not configured OpenMP correctly. GCC need an option -fopenmp to enable OpenMP. Similar configuration may be necessary for VS.

Comment: yes I enabled openMP in VS (project/properties/language/useopenmp), also the program loads vcomp90.dll which is openmp dll...

Comment: okay i know now - pragma omp for doestn work - I had to type pragma omp parallel for...